# JSF. How to set a value of JavaScript function to a field of Bean?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ejb, ajax4jsf

Good morning! How to set a value of JavaScript function to a field of Enterprice Java Bean?
I have the js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTimezone() {
      var d = new Date()
      var gmtMinutes = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
      return gmtMinutes;
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to use:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="timezone" assignTo="MyBean.gmtMinutes">
       <a4j:actionparam name="timezone" value="getUserId()"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

But I did not get. I think that I incorrectly used the tag a4j:jsFunction. Give me advice please how to use the tag correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a `jsFunction` which sends parameter's value to server:

```
        <a4j:jsFunction name="updateTimeZone">
            <a4j:param name="timezone" assignTo="#{MyBean.gmtMinutes}"/>
        </a4j:jsFunction>
```

And then invoke that `jsFunction` from JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendTimezoneToServer() {
      var d = new Date()
      var gmtMinutes = -d.getTimezoneOffset();
      updateTimeZone(gmtMinutes);
    }
</script>
```

There is also an example of the same on RichFaces Showcase:
http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=jsFunction&skin=blueSky

Comment: Thank you! But what to write to "name"? Is name="timezone" correct?

Comment: @Andrei It does not matter in this case, name it 'timezone' or 'param1'. It is name of parameter of generated js function (like this: function updateTimeZone(timezone)).

Comment: @Andrei Can you be more constructive. What exactly is causing the problem? Did you check the example from RichFaces showcase? Just a guess: do you have a form around your jsFunction?

Comment: I have found the cause, thank you. It turned out I had to just add another function call